# Check each <select> for values

Tags: jquery

I have an list of checkout items in and unordered list with  dropdowns in each:

```
<li class="item">
  <select name="item-custom>
    <option value="" selected></option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
  </select>
</li>
<li class="item">
  <select name="item-custom>
    <option value="" selected></option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
  </select>
</li>
```

...

I'm trying to check each `li.item select` and see if it has a value, and if not append an error inside of the .item:

```
if( $('.item select').val() == '') {
  $($(this).closest('li')).append('<div class="error">Custom is required.</div>');
}
```

It seems to only pick up if the first `li.item select` is empty, and not the entire list.

Comment: I'd recommend using jquery validator plugin to save you from doing extra work.

Comment: @Chad - Did you get this working, or did we misunderstand your question?

Answer (score 0):

This page shows how to iterate over list items, you could still use your test to determine empty listitems: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 0):

Use `.each()`:

```
$(".item select").each(
    function(index, element)
    {
        if ($(element).val() == "")
        {
            $(element).closest('li').append('<div class="error">Custom is required.</div>');
        }
    }
);
```

By the way, you can (and should) chain JQuery calls together, rather than nest them.

```
$($(this).closest('li'))
```

...is much better as

```
$(this).closest("li")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.item option:nth-child(1):selected')
               .closest('li')
               .append('<div class="error">Custom is required.</div>');
```

- Select all `option` elements that are the first child of their parent, and are selected,
- Traverse up to the `<li>`
- Do the `.append()`

This will have no effect on `<select>` elements where a different option is selected.

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZUAdc/)**

**Result:**

[image]

---

Or like this if you prefer:

```
$('.item option[value=""]:selected')
    .closest('li')
    .append('<div class="error">Custom is required.</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try instead:

```
$('.item select').each(
    function(){
        if ($(this).val() == ''){
            $(this).closest('li').append('<div class="error">Custom is required.</div>');
        }
    });
```